# Using awk to replace text between two strings or patterns

Tags: mysql, wordpress, awk

I had a question ongoing here but I'm new to stack and somehow the thread got locked or removed: [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750311/mysql-database-replacing-text-within-the-post-content-with-wildcard-between-two)

I'm working with a WordPress database with 60,000 or so "posts" inside the "post_content" column I want to remove those `<p>` html tags and the text in between them. . My post content looks like this:

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #fffff;">
An entire paragraph of text around 200 words
</span></p>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="309" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
```

The `p` tags are going to be identical and only occur once per post, the exception is for the color which may possible be different on some posts.

Expected output should be like this:

```
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="309" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
```

I want to remove all the text in the paragraph tags. So what I would like to remove is the text "An entire paragraph of text around 200 words" This text is different on every single post but the one constant is the `<p>` open and close tag.

From my last question this command: By user "PS."

```
awk '/<p/,/<\/p>/{next} {print $0}' inputfile
```

Was ran on the .sql database after i had dumped it. But the text was still present after looking at the database.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Update: This question was solved by: Ed Morton

```
Using GNU awk for multi-char RS this:
awk -v RS='</p>\\s*' -v ORS= '{sub(/<p.*/,"")} 1' file
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier using a scripting language having html parsing libraries.

Comment: That awk seems to work on the data you provided. You do realize that it's not an infile edit command but it outputs the processed file to stdout and you need to store that to a file?

Comment: @JamesBrown Update: Did a little research and figured out how to dump the output back into an sql file. So I ran this command:
`awk '/<p/,/<\/p>/{next} {print $0}' test.sql > test_awk.sql`
The problem is when I did this there were not any posts left in the database. All the posts were deleted. In the table "wp_posts" and everything was deleted from "wp_options" [looks like this after running that awk command](http://prntscr.com/d0uc1g)

Comment: `perl -pe 's/<p>.+?<\/p>//g' < test.sql > test_perl.sql`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I ran that command exactly swapping file names out of course. imported the sql file and looked at the post_content and I see the text was still present. It does not appear to have removed the text or altered the html tags. Not sure whats wrong but i thought for sure i'd have better results with your suggestion. Any ideas?

Comment: My mistake. It should be `perl -pe 's/<p[^>]*>.+?<\/p>//g' < test.sql > test_perl.sql`

Comment: According to the comment under it, your previous question was deleted because it was downvoted for being a poor question (see [ask]) and had no answers after a month. This is still a poor question as it's missing required information like the expected output given that sample input so YMMV this time around too. Post a [mcve].

Comment: @EdMorton My apologies I've updated the question with the expected output.  The code posted in my question does produce erroneous output. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for adding that. Now that you've added the expected output, this is a VERY different question from what you appeared to be asking. Removing everything between `<p>` and `</p>` is trivial, leaving all of the tags like `<span...>` and `</span>` but removing everything else is much harder. Why do you want those left though when there's nothing between them for them to operate on? Your input shows that you only have 1 `<p>...</p>` pair in the whole file - does that truly represent your real data? If not then show multiple occurrences in your example as that's harder to deal with than 1.

Comment: @EdMorton Sir I initially thought leaving these tags would make it easier to target the text between them while making it more complicated to remove both the tags and the text. As you have informed me it would be entirely easier to remove the tags and the text completely I am again going to update my question with the expected result. I appreciate your help and would be delighted if you could help with removing the tags + text in between.

Comment: And is there just one `<p>...</p>` pair in the whole file or can there be multiple? It makes a huge difference to the potential solutions. If it's just 1 then your sample input/output is fine, if there can be more than 1 then edit your question to show at least 2.

Comment: @EdMorton There is only one pair of paragraph tags per post which are identical except for the color which I've updated the question to specify.

Comment: OK so that tells us what there is per "post" but we don't know what a "post" is since we don't work in your domain and you still haven't told us how many "post"s there are per input file. All we know is what you tell us so keep it clear and simple for us and don't assume we know anything about your domain.

Comment: @EdMorton Again I apologize. I'm working with a wordpress database with 60,000 or so "posts" inside the "post_content" column I'm removing those `<p>` html tags and the text in between them.

Comment: OK, so now you have to explain what a "post_content" column is. Again, we do not know your domain. That sounds like within your input file what you have shown us so far is contained in 1 of many "columns" (separated by what?) - that would, of course, be enormously significant to any tool trying to search for text within your file. If that is the case then that would certainly explain why none of the answers work for you so, again, [edit] your question to show truly a representative input **FILE**, not 1 "post" within one "post_content column" within the file, and the associated expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS this:

```
awk -v RS='</p>\\s*' -v ORS= '{sub(/<p.*/,"")} 1' file
```

will work whether there's just 1 or multiple `<p...</p>` pairs in the file, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #fffff;">
First entire paragraph of text around 200 words
</span></p>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="309" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #fffff;">
Second entire paragraph of text around 200 words
</span></p>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="309" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS='</p>\\s*' -v ORS= '{sub(/<p.*/,"")} 1' file
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="309" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="309" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
```

The above is obviously fragile and can fail if, for example `<p` can appear in `[Text_between_brackets]`. The more of the `<p...` line you can specify in the `sub()` the less fragile it will be, e.g. MAYBE you can/should do something more like this:

```
awk -v RS='</p>\\s*' -v ORS= '{sub(/<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: /,"")} 1' file
```

Comment: I dumped the current database which is working. I run:

`awk -v RS='</p>\\s*' -v ORS= '{sub(/<p.*/,"")} 1' db_dump.sql > db_dump_awk.sql`

I get this error when trying to re-import the sql file into a new empty database:
`ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 328: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

I also tried it with the edited code and that one is not removing the tag or the text.

Comment: Additionally I just tried to dump the database and reimport the dumped .sql file into a newly created database and it does not throw the error so long as I do not run the awk command on the file.

Comment: Does the script I posted print the expected output given your posted sample input? If not, in what way is it different? If it does exactly what you want for your sample input but fails for your real input, then your sample input does not truly represent your real input and you'll have to figure out and post a more truly representative example. If it does not work on your sample input then maybe you are not using GNU awk or your input is not the same as you posted, tell us the symptoms of the failure/difference if you'd like help debugging it.

Comment: Basically I run the command in terminal and it finishes without printing anything nor an error. I assume the command ran successfully. I'm not sure if I need to install GNU awk separately or not. After some debugging on my end I see it does strip the target text on the real input within the .sql file but leaves me with an error when trying to import that .sql file into a new database.

Comment: That sounds like the script does what you want it to do, but what you want it to do generates invalid SQL. You'll have to figure out what it is you really need to do and then ask for help to do THAT if necessary.

Comment: The good news is I got it to work thanks to you. I dumped a slightly older copy of the same database which was abused slightly less with phpmyadmin search and replacing and for some reason it worked. Not very scientific but the regex and command you placed in your answer was indeed working an fully functional. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try below sed command -

```
sed '/<p/,/<\/p/d' kk.txt
```

Need to use escape character for `</p`.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. I tried the command on a copy of the database.sql then imported the database into mysql and checked it through phpmyadmin. It still showed the paragraph text. When I ran the exact command you posted it looked like it was searching and replacing but when I checked it as I said the text was still present.
`<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #2c8ebf;">
This text was still present </span></p></br>`

Comment: Update: OK so I did the sed command like this: `sed -i '/<p/,/<\/p/d' test_sed.sql`

Now the result was there were no posts and lots of missing tables after I ran the command. I checked the data base after using the sed command and importing the db then looking at it through phpmyadmin. Am I still doing something wrong? It looks like the code you sent does indeed escape the slashes.

Comment: @d.ariel yes, your regex is too "greedy."  You need to match `<p>` followed by any number of characters *except* `</p>`, then followed by `</p>`.  Otherwise `Too<p>This Thing</p>something that should not be removed<p>That thing</p> Little` is reduced to `Too Little` because the entire `<p>...</p>` was matched.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Should I be using awk or sed? Both bits of regex were "greedy" with either command I used. The exact text is like this:
`<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #2c8ebf;">
Text I want removed. </span></p>`
They all start out with `<p style="text-align: left:">` Could you give me some better regex by chance?

Comment: @d.ariel - Can you share some data of input file related to your current file where the text  is still present that you don't want to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use awk or sed or perl. It's difficult to manage the regular expressions correctly, as you've discovered. There's an old joke:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.
>   — Jamie Zawinski, 1997

I wouldn't even dump the data and edit the dump file. That's difficult too.

An easier solution is to use XPath functions built into MySQL to manipulate each post directly inside the database. I tested the following solution, querying a version of your sample post content, with the `<p>` tag (and everything within it) stripped out.

```
mysql> SELECT post_content, 
       UpdateXml(post_content, '/p', '') AS post_content_without_p 
       FROM posts\G
```

And the output showing the before and after content is:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          post_content: <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #fffff;">
An entire paragraph of text around 200 words
</span></p>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="309" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>

post_content_without_p: 
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="309" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
[Text_between_brackets]
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO"></iframe>
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The [UpdateXml()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html#function_updatexml) function is part of MySQL's documented built-in functions. It takes three arguments:

- The column or expression to read, which should contain XML (HTML is a subset of XML).
- The XPath expression of what part of that XML to match.
- A replacement string to substitute for the XML you matched.

Once you're satisfied that your query does what you want, you can update the content in your table without dumping and restoring:

```
mysql> UPDATE posts SET post_content = UpdateXml(post_content, '/p', '');
```

Always make a backup before you try a change like this! Or else copy the data to another database while you experiment.